# .htaccess 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get /mom/products/14 to redirect to /mom/product.php?id=14

The code I am using in my .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ product.php?id=$1
```

But when I go to /mom/products/14 I get a 404 error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also have my .htaccess in the /mom/ folder if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need slash at the very end of the pattern:

```
    RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1
```